# Google+ API "400 (Bad Request)" and "Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." errors

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-authentication

I am trying to integrate the G+ API with [my website](http://www.pricewombat.com) and am having a problem. If you look at the console when loading the page, you will see the following errors:

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pricewombat.com 400 (Bad Request) cb=gapi.loaded_0:436

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pricewombat.com#rpctoken=356505585&forcesecure=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I'm just using the example code given on Google's website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=googlePlusOnloadCallback';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

If I run `gapi.auth.signIn()` in the console, nothing happens. I'm assuming the problem is related to the above errors when the page loads.

What's causing this problem and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I created a blank page on my website with this barebones code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'http://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried loading the above page with and without the authentication meta tags (not shown above) and am still getting the errors.

It seems like this *has* to be a problem on Google's end since I'm just using the most basic barebones example code and it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, apparently Google+ just had a brainfart or something, because the solution was simply to clear my cookies!

I tried using my website on another computer and the Google+ API worked fine (no errors), so I tried clearing the cookies on my desktop and lo and behold, it started working!

Comment: What's hilarious is that every few months I get this error, google it, and find my own answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that if the client has opened up the chrome for very long time, they would get this error. Once they close the chrome and reopen, they don't have any trouble with the issue. My solution was to download the script from the server, uploaded it to our server and made it as a backup download.