# How do I avoid this X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN error when running the Google "Hello Analytics" API tutorial?

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

I've been trying to run the https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api tutorial to get up and running with pulling data programmatically from Google Analytics.

I've copied the sample files exactly, but when I access them via localhost in Chrome, I get the following error in the JavaScript console, and get redirected to `about:blank` :

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=363192057646-fbj7q1oais...%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&state=327475409%7C0.2024869166&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I've tried all manner of tweaks but can't get this error to go away. Hope someone can assist (or indeed just direct me to a simple, working, Javascript example for accessing the Google Analytics API.

Answer (score 17):

Please check the **Authorized JavaScript origins**
 url in the Google API console in your Oauth Settings. This must be where you are authorising the javascript.

Comment: The setting is here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials (at time of writing)

Comment: For me I had to and add the https origin (and remove the http origin)

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue yesterday but then I realised I was using the wrong Client ID on my Credentials.

You should double check if you created a 'Client ID for web application' on **APIs & auth > Credentials**. And then use that Client ID.

I my case, I wrongly created a 'Service Account' first and used that Client ID. Then I realised the mistake and created a '*Web Application*' and replaced the Client ID on hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.js (according to the tutorial on https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api).

Btw, don't forget to create a Public API Access key.

**EDIT:** if you are using [the google example](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/analytics/v3/auth_util.js) fix the following function:

```
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
    gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3', handleAuthorized);
  } else {
    handleUnauthorized();
  }
}
```

On the if statement, change to:

```
if (authResult && !authResult.error)
```

So you would end up with:

```
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3', handleAuthorized);
  } else {
    handleUnauthorized();
  }
}
```

My colleague found the bug and made a [pull request](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/pull/183) to fix it. I hope that sorts the issue now. It sorted for me ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did wonder about Service Account vs Web Application so it's good to know that is the right option. However I have tried again and I still get the same error from the sample files as in the tutorial. From the version in the client library version on github, I get a different error: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/182

Comment: So we are facing the same issue now... I've managed to avoid the X-Frame-Options issue but I get the 'Login required' error. I'll keep a look at the github issue as well.

Comment: It's VERY IMPORTANT to create and set an API key, so don't forget!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with a Fusion table example I found online.

None of the answers I found online were useful at all but I finally solved the issue as follows:

Open the dev console in Chrome which shows the error and the url it is trying to access, open the Url in a new tab.

The page shows this:

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_request
Parameter not allowed for this message type: client_secret
```

So I edited the code:

```
  function auth(immediate) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      <!--client_secret: clientSecret,-->
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: immediate
    }, handleAuthResult);
  }
```

Et voila (:

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message many times before.
Most of the time I just did call Google API inconsistently.
To figure out, click the URL in the dev. console. A new window opens and you get a message like this:

```
400.
That’s an error.
Error: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes were invalid ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I got it to work by clearning my cookies. 
--Solution posted in this similar issue here: [Google+ API "400 (Bad Request)" and "Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681594/google-api-400-bad-request-and-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-i)

Comment: closing the browser and/or clearing the cookies does not work