# X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' in Android PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate my application with Google Drive using Javascript.

I have done the complete step:  While running the application in device i am getting the below issue:

**CordovaLog(5290): :** `Line 0 : Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=....///' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Could somebody help me out here!! Here is the code which i have used in Cordova App.

[Google drive integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js)

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545465/how-do-i-avoid-this-x-frame-options-sameorigin-error-when-running-the-google-he

Comment: My application working perfectly in web browser But I have problem with device .I have followed this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you may want to use the instructions here: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Comment: @EricKoleda thanks let me try..

Comment: @EricKoleda is there any possibility to solved the above issue..I have tried the above link.But no hope!!