# Google's own demo of their Analytics API forbidden by SAMEORIGIN

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-api, same-origin-policy

I'm just getting started looking at the Google Analytics API which should allow me to embed some Analytics data into a page. I have found two pages containing almost identical demo code, both created by Google themselves:

- https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide

and neither of them works. Nothing loads, and the error message in the Console is:

**Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&origin=MY_URL&state=1729197785%7C0.713338618&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

Can anyone explain why this would be? The Client ID isn't the problem, I've double-checked, and there are no restrictions on referrers. This happens when the code is place in a live public web page, not locally on an intranet or localhost page.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live page?

Comment: I can make another one in about five minutes I guess, but I don't think it will tell you anything more than you see above.

Comment: Well, based on what I've seen above, I'm not sure what the problem is. So if you don't link me to to a demo, I'm not sure how else I can help you.

Comment: The problem is, as you can read above, "Nothing loads, and the error message in the Console is:

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&origin=MY_URL&state=1729197785%7C0.713338618&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." Not sure what you need. Also you could just download the code from the URLs provided and test it for yourself in about 30 seconds.

Comment: I have tried it, and it works for me. Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681594/google-api-400-bad-request-and-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-i