# How to use the YouTube API inside an Electron app?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, electron

I'm trying to implements the basic [JavaScript Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) inside an Electron app. I've successfully created my project and added an API key credentials in the [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

However, when I try the basic samples into an Electron app, I get the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

What should I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Client ID can be the issue.  [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545465/how-do-i-avoid-this-x-frame-options-sameorigin-error-when-running-the-google-he)

You can also use CORS if that does not work:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: I'm already using a "Web Client" Client ID. With the CORS solution, I get a 403 with the first example, and I can't get an access token cause calling `authorize` fail for the same reason as the question.

Comment: I set up a [web project](https://github.com/YannBertrand/YoutubeApiExample) and get exactly the same issue.

Comment: [Found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681594/google-api-400-bad-request-and-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-i)

Comment: should always use private browsing mode when testing and disable cache in dev tools.

Comment: Have you got an idea on how to do that inside an Electron app?

Comment: use browser-window.webPreferences.partition option to isolate session/cookies or make it in-memory so it isn't stored.

Comment: I've set the browser window `webPreferences.partition` to `''`, `'test'` and `'persist:test'`, none of these values resolve the problem... What do you mean by "make it in-memory"?

Comment: look at the electron doc.  depends what version too possibly.

Comment: I can't find it... I guess it's only possible by doing this [server-side](http://iamemmanouil.com/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/)